# how to detect iBeacon incase of multiple iBeacons available

Tags: ios

I read some tutorials regarding `iBeacons`, `UUID`, `Major` and `Minor`. I got that in case of multiple `iBeacons` found, based on `UUID`, `Major` and `Minor` number we can handle respected one. I also read that `iBeacon` always broadcasting `UUID`, `Major` and `Minor` numbers.

All I need to know is how do I know these `UUID`, `Major` and `Minor` number to detect one `iBeacon` in my application. Are these identities given along with `iBeacon`? In case I have to handle 20 `iBeacon` through my application, how to set `Major` and `Minor` numbers for all these `iBeacons`?

Kindly let me know these `UUID`, `Major` and `Minor` numbers of `iBeacons`.

```
self.firstRegion=[[ESTBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID: ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID major:52415 minor:85642 identifier:@"firstBeaconRegion"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know what UUID you are *looking for*, it means you have to program your beacons so that they broadcast the signal you want (`UUID Major Minor` values), this can be done using the SDK provided by your beacons seller, or if your using another iOS device you have to configure the signal via the CoreLocation framework.

Or else use the default information already inside the beacons you purchased but I recommend you to change those parameters to the one you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for responding .."use default information already inside the beacons".what the information that we can know about beacon device by default. can every beacon has it UUID major and Minor numbers by default?? incase of that how can we know default information...please do reply ..

Comment: Every beacon bought should have a default signal (usually they cannot be turned on/off so they must be working when you buy them), the info about the signal are "declared" by the one who built it! It means that the seller should have told you the info OR should have given you an application or similar to discover. If he didn't I guess you should contact him otherwise I don't know if you will be able to retrieve them. Actually you just need to know the UUID, and automatically you will be able to know Major/Minor of each beacon